# Moving through multiple datagridviews vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I have multiple datagridviews on one form, with different datasources, i need to make buttons (next, previous, last, first) that will move through currently "focused" gridview, so far i tried

```
If DataGridView1.ContainsFocus Then
      Me.BindingSource1.MoveNext()

ElseIf DataGridView2.ContainsFocus Then
      Me.BindingSource2.MoveNext()
Else
' blablabla
End If
```

and this

```
If DataGridView1.focused Then
       Me.BindingSource1.MoveNext()

ElseIf DataGridView2.focused Then
       Me.BindingSource2.MoveNext()
Else
'blablabla
End If
```

every statement is false, even when i click on gridview, datasources are connected, so when i select random row from datagridview1 i datagridview2 has its first row selected

Comment: button is focus when you click it, so focused is not going to work

Comment: what you mean by this: hat will move through currently "focused" gridview, so far i tried?  Originally i thought you wanted to move from datagridview to another

Comment: i want to move through datagridview with buttons (next, previous....) that will move selected row in datagridview to next,previous... but when i have multiple datagridviews i need to see which datagridview is "focused" and move next,prev row on THAT datagridveiw

Comment: Set their tabindex and let the user press [Tab]

Answer (score 0):

You can either do what Plutonix wrote or:

You can keep an index of which `control` last had `focus`. Pretty much lots of working with `events`.

For one you need to set up `event handler` for each `datagridview lostfocus` and store it's name in `index`. Why because when you `click button`, the `button` has `focus` so you have to know which `datagridview` had `focus`.

If you want to move between `cells` or `rows` you need to use `event`: `DataGridView.SelectionChanged Event`  and store cell's row and `datagridview`

Try it post it here, we help you finish.